# "Do not buy hardware wallet from a 3rd party seller" security tip, does it apply if authorized in the official website?

Tags: wallet-security, hardware-wallet, ledger-hardware-wallet

"Do not buy hardware wallet from a 3rd party seller" It's a well-known security guideline for newbies. I wonder though, does it apply for 3rd party sellers that are listed on the official website of the product? E.g. [Ledger reseller](https://www.ledger.com/reseller)? If not safe, and you still decide to buy from there, how can you ensure the device hasn't been tampered with?

Comment: https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404389367057-Is-my-Ledger-device-genuine-

Answer (score 1):

For Ledger, you SHOULD be ok buying from an authorized reseller, although it is usually recommended to buy from Ledger itself directly.

Ledger Live will tell you if it is a genuine device or not.  Also make sure you generating a new key when you first use your device.